# Rendering a JSON String inside a ASP.NET Layout

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

So I have a form in which you enter a few parameters, and it returns the form inputs back to the model. I then use in an [HttpPost] response in my controller to first input the results of the form into a method to return back a C# object from my API. Here's a sample

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyView(MyModel myModelResponse) 
{
var myVar = myModelResponse.UID;
var myVar2 = myModelRepsonse.name;
ObjectMethod myMethod = new ObjectMethod // calls new object 
var myObject = myMethod.ObjectMethodObject(myVar, myVar2);

string JsonObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);

return JsonObject;
}
```

I serialize my object using JSON.NET into a JSON string. I want to return the JSON string along with my layout that has navigation. How do I return both the JSON string and the layout in the post response view?

Thanks for the help!

Edit - Here's my view as requested:

```
@{ 

Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}

<html>
<body> @using (Html.BeginForm()) {

@Html.ValidationSummary()
<p> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UID) </p> 
<p> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)</p> 

<input type="submit" value="Submit Object" /> 
}
```

Comment: If this isn't an ajax request, why are you serialising to Json and not just creating a normal Razor view that has a model of the same type as `myObject`?

Comment: The object is bound to change a lot, so redefining the model every time the object is updated is a pain. Using reflection would also be tough on the object since it has dictionaries

Comment: What do you mean you want to return the layout? Can you show your view and what you're trying to accomplish? Seems like you're posting to a regular controller but serializing to JSON, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Then make your view model type `dynamic` perhaps?

Comment: Actually, thinking about this a bit more, how are you expecting to process the Json in your view?

Comment: I will update my view in the post. I'm parsing the JSON in my view with json.human.js.

Answer (score 2):

As you want to return the entire layout in your view, I would suggest that you don't serialise it at all and just pass the object itself to the view. For example:

View:

```
@model SomeObject
//View code goes here
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyView(MyModel myModelResponse) 
{
    var myVar = myModelResponse.UID;
    var myVar2 = myModelRepsonse.name;
    ObjectMethod myMethod = new ObjectMethod // calls new object 
    var myObject = myMethod.ObjectMethodObject(myVar, myVar2);

    return View(myObject);
}
```

However, if you absolutely insist on using the Json string in the view, then pass it as a string:

View:

```
@model string

<script type="text/javascript">
    var jsonData = @Model;
    //snip
</script>
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyView(MyModel myModelResponse) 
{
    var myVar = myModelResponse.UID;
    var myVar2 = myModelRepsonse.name;
    ObjectMethod myMethod = new ObjectMethod // calls new object 
    var myObject = myMethod.ObjectMethodObject(myVar, myVar2);

    string JsonObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);

    return View(JsonObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Json()` method to return an `Anonymous` type. The anonymous type can contain properties.

E.g.

```
public ActionResult MyView(MyModel myModelResponse)
{
    // ... You logic goes here to fetch the Json data and layout data.
    return Json(new 
    { 
        result = JsonObject,
        layout = LayoutData
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i do this very often, try this

In your controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyView(MyModel myModelResponse) 
{
    //code
   YourModelClass model = new YourModelClass();
    // mapping or mode code
   return View(model);
}
```

In your view :

```
@model YourModelClass

@{
  string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model);
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myJsonObject = @Html.Raw(json);
</script>
```

That way you still have access and intellisense to your model object @Model